# Организация хранения и генерации классов

Tags: c++

Активно использую классы, но никогда на практике не использовал - наследование и полиморфизм, кроме как учебные задания, и использую классы как обобщение переменных и функций в одном месте...

Интересует вопрос.Допустим у нас есть класс планета. И класс солнечная система. В классе солнечная система есть параметр - вместимость. Допустим от 1000 до 2000 планет. Координаты планет хранятся в двумерном массиве. 0 - пустота, 1,2 ... n - планеты.

```
0 0 1 0 
2 3 0 0
5 6 0 4
0 8 0 7
```

Интересует вопрос. Как можно реализовать:

1) Генерация солнечной система - число планет, по этому числу создаются планеты и им присваиваются координаты

2) Параметры классов солнечная система и все планеты сохраняются в фале (ini,txt ....). И их можно загрузить из файла.

3) Генерация солнечной системы, а именно создание планет еще и выбирает какую именно планету мы выбираем, допустим у нас есть класс родитель Planet и дочерние классы LivePlanet, MoonPlanet, UsualPlanet, у них у всех есть свои функции и свои параметры естественно.

Comment: Здравствуйте, а можно полный код для примера пожалуйста!! А если есть на питоне то тоже, плииз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Если бы у вас в классе вместо двумерного массива был `std::vector<Planet*> planets` вы бы могли сделать генерацию планет примерно так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < planetsCount; i++){
  planets.push_back(new Planet);
}
```

Comment: Окей моя оплошность, я еще не привык использовать высокоуровневые методы хранения данных, такие как вектора. Но собственно как организовать хранение со всеми параметрами, и как нам обращаться к new Planet?

Comment: Все параметры в классе - он и хранится в векторе. Обращаться к new Planet не надо, достаточно написать planets[0]->SomeMethod(foo, bar) чтобы обратиться к первому элементу вектора.

Comment: Я говорю именно про хранение в файле. И я так понял про мой третий вопрос легче выбирать лично рандомом или как нибудь еще какой будет планета.

Comment: Хранение в файле - это надо в сторону сериализации смотреть, я подобное руками делаю если надо, но у этого подхода найдется много противников.

Comment: Посоветуйте литературу по поводу сериализации и расширенного использования классов, например как в моем случае.

Comment: Единственная книга, которую я читал по ООП - был Страуструп, поэтому ничего не могу посоветовать. Касательно сериализации - ищите статьи по теме.

Comment: Хотя ответ и правильный, но он плохой. Вы выделяете память, а кто её будет освобождать? Для этого в C++ есть умные указатели, использование голых указатель не рекомендуется(очень сильно)

Comment: @ixSci: Может быть, дадите альтернативный ответ (и скажете два слова про умные указатели)?

Comment: @VladD, тут Владимиру две строчки исправить, не хочу ещё один ответ давать. Тем более, что этот уже принят.

Comment: @ixSci напишите тут

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю на вопрос «как сгенерировать солнечную систему»: тут можно использовать типичный приём — фабрика(псевдокод):

```
enum class PlanetType{Live, Usual, Moon};

std::unique_ptr<Planet> createPlanet(PlanetType type, arguments...)
{
    switch(type)
    {
    case PlanetType::Live:
        return std::make_unique<LivePlanet>(arguments...);
    case PlanetType::Usual:
        return std::make_unique<UsualPlanet>(arguments...);
    case PlanetType::Moon:
        return std::make_unique<MoonPlanet>(arguments...);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Planet>> planets;
    for(...)
    {
        PlanetType type == getTypeFromSomewhere;
        planets.emplace_back(createPlanet(type, getArgumentsFromSomewhere))
    }
}
```

Таким образом Вы получите вектор, в котором содержатся все планеты. НО, с моей точки зрения, наследование тут вообще никаким боком не подходит. Я считаю, что тип планеты надуман и от того, является ли планета спутником другой или нет, её поведение совершенно не меняется. Наследование же необходимо тогда, когда поведение различных наследников может быть разным и вызывая полиморфную функцию, каждый наследник ведёт себя по-своему.

Я не вижу где Земля ведёт себя отлично от Юпитера. Да у них разная масса, разный химический состав, но это детали, которые на поведение не влияют.

Comment: Я привёл данный пример просто из головы, тем более мне интересен больше вопрос сохранения и загрузки классов